# How to get the txHash of a transaction?

Tags: transactions, web3j, java

I have this method where I make a transaction to the network rinkeby, but to know how I can get the hash of the transaction made. I am using java with web3j, in addition to using infura to connect to the network.

```
public void CrearCertificado(CareerCertificate careercertificate, String id, BigInteger fecha, String nombre, String rutalumno, String instituto, String rutinstituto, String titulo,
                                                        String totalhash, String fechatitulacion, String registronumber, String codigoV ) throws Exception{
```

`careercertificate
                    .createCertificate(id, fecha, nombre, rutalumno, instituto, rutinstituto, titulo, totalhash, fechatitulacion, registronumber, codigoV )
                    .send();

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
careercertificate
    .createCertificate(id, fecha, nombre, rutalumno, instituto, rutinstituto, titulo, totalhash, fechatitulacion, registronumber, codigoV )
    .send().getTransactionHash()
```

Comment: Yes, I started reading the documentation and saw some examples and everything went well. Thanks for answering

Comment: How could I get the input data through a txHash? @ivicaa

Comment: @ivicaa, this should return hash *after tx has been mined*. Is it possible to get tx hash *before*? Tx receives hash when it has been put in pool and wait for mining.